# Data analysis tool for Java

Tags: java, data-analysis

I need to find some Java tools that work similar to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) in Python. pandas is a tool that provides high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools.

I have a few .csv files in AWS S3 that store large amounts of data (like 80 MB). What I want to achieve is using Java, I want to make some data analysis on it, like joining data, processing it, merging together different columns from .csv file. I know that it’s easy to achieve in Python with the pandas library. But not sure, how hard is it to do in Java?

pandas, for example, has data structures called DataFrames, which is great for my use-case.

*Note:* I cannot use Python for certain reasons, because this goal that I'm trying to achieve should be as part of our DataPipeline, which is already written in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Weka](http://weka.waikato.ac.nz/). It is implemented in Java, has several GUIs and can be called via the command line, or by importing the package(s) into Java code.

Weka can import CSV files, but it works best with its own inputfile format .arff (= csv with a metadata header). There are csv2arff converter availabel but I use R to convert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use esProc SPL (structured preprocessing language) to realize your requirements. Integrate several jar packages and call SPL. For quick understanding, refer to Java computing layer http://c.raqsoft.com/article/1586764200868

Both SPL and Pandas are professional structured data processing tools, but SPL is simpler and implemented in Java. It provides parallel multi-threaded computing and streaming processing capabilities with better performance. It has many built-in data access interfaces, which can easily connect various data sources and obtain data from them.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, and I'm not a Java programmer, but [Joinery](https://github.com/cardillo/joinery) looks like it trying to be like pandas but in Java. It even refers to pandas in its GitHub readme.

Answer (score 0):

[DataMelt software program](https://jwork.org/dmelt) is very similar to Pandas. This is a collection of scientific Java libraries that are all interfaced with Jython. It is well designed for data analysis and data mining.

Comment: Please disclose any affiliation you have with this product.

Comment: I'm a web admin where this (and many other) program is located. Not associated with this program in any other way